# Get this._id of collection instance in template.foo.rendered

Tags: javascript, mongodb, templates, meteor, semantic-ui

I try to include the rating module from Semantic UI (http://semantic-ui.com/modules/rating.html) under articles for users to be able to rate them. If  user rates the article, the article id is stored into Meteor.user().profile.ratedItems.

If user goes away from the article to another one and then comes back to the first one the rating module should be rendered as read-only(so the user is not able to rate the same article again).

The problem is that I do not know how to check if article _id is stored in Meteor.user().profile.ratedItems in template.foo.rendered because this._id gives not article id but id of template.

In template.foo.events and template.foo.helpers I can check for that by the sentence _.contains(Meteor.user().profile.ratedItems,this._id) and it works OK everywhere but of cause not in template.foo.rendered. Now even if user rates an article more then one time the rating in db does not change. But I need to solve the "visual" issue.

So here is the code:

JS:

```
    Template.foo.helpers({

    rate: function () {
        return Math.floor(this.rating);
    },
    state : function () {
        if (Meteor.userId()) {
            if (_.contains(Meteor.user().profile.ratedItems,this._id)) {
                return "rated"
            } else {return "unrated"}
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    },
    statetext: function () {
        if (Meteor.userId()) {
            if (_.contains(Meteor.user().profile.ratedItems,this._id)) {
                return "Overall rating:" }
            else { return "Rate the article:"}
        } else {
            return "Overall rating:"
        }
    }
});

Template.foo.rendered = function() {
    if (Meteor.userId()) {
        if (_.contains(Meteor.user().profile.ratedItems,this._id)) {
            $('.ui.rating').rating('disable');
        } else {
            $('.ui.rating').rating();
        }
    } else {
        $('.ui.rating').rating('disable');
    }
};

Template.foo.events({
    'click .unrated': function () {
        var addedRating = $('.unrated').rating('get rating');
        var currentArticleId = this._id;
        var newsum = this.rating_sum+addedRating;
        var newcount = this.rating_count+1;
        var newrating = newsum/newcount;
        Schools.update(currentSchoolId,{$inc: {rating_count:1}});
        Schools.update(currentSchoolId,{$inc: {rating_sum:addedRating}});
        Schools.update(currentSchoolId,{$set: {rating:newrating}});
        Meteor.users.update({_id:Meteor.userId()},{$push: {'profile.ratedItems':currentArticleId}});
        $('.ui.rating').rating({"set rating":Math.floor(newrating)});
        $('.ui.rating').rating('disable');
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<template name="schoolPage">
<div class="ui center aligned blue segment">
     {{#if currentUser}}{{statetext}}{{else}}Overall rating:{{/if}}
   <div class="ui tiny heart rating {{state}}" data-rating="{{rate}}" data-max-rating="5"></div>
</div>
</template>
```

I thought about using Session.set and Session.get but did not come to any solution yet.
Thank you for help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `this`, you can use `Template.currentData` inside the `rendered` callback.

See the docs at http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_currentdata.

Comment: Just changed `this._id` in `Template.foo.rendered` to `Template.currentData()._id` and it worked great.
Thank you.